# heroku: setup local development with an addon

Tags: heroku, foreman

I'd like to develop a heroku app with the neo4j addon, and i've followed the instructions  [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com//articles/neo4j#local-setup-get-neo4j) but I'm lost as to how to integrate the heroku-like environment variables into my local development environment.

My major goals:

1. Make things behave as similarly as possible to the deployed app.
2. Allow me to run automated test suites locally.
3. Allow me to run the app locally, for quick development iteration.

The only heroku helpcenter article I've found ([here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)) that deals with this seems to recommend always deploying, but this means I have to check-in and push every little edit I make, syntax errors and all, and doesn't allow for running automated tests locally.

It seems like there should be a way for me to edit my Foreman Procfiles to get the desired behavior, but I don't see how I can do that without affecting the deployed processes as well.

Answer (score 2):

This article seems to be what I needed, although I'm still not sure how I was supposed to find it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup

In summary, you can do `heroku config > .env` to install the production environment locally, then edit the file as needed. Foreman then uses this file to set environment variables.

The article recommends adding the `.env` file to `.gitignore`, but as far as I can tell, checking it in is safe since it seems heroku seems to already override it.